# Access a binded variable from different class c# ranorex

Tags: c#, data-binding, ranorex

Iam using rest sharp in ranorex
Hi I have created a folder called data providers and I have inserted module variables like this

```
string _fname = "";
[TestVariable(""afaf**********)]
public string fname
{
get { return _fname; }
set { _fname = value; }
}
```

I tried to access fname from different class like
objectname.fname and it returns null.

CAn you please tell me how to get the value which is binded to fname from a different class?

Comment: `fname` is an instance property, it's not static. Therefore, you need an instance of `objectname` or what ever that class is called before accessing `fname`. Or on the other hand `fname` would need to be static, but I wouldn't recommend that. Also the attribute doesn't look right to me: `[TestVariable(""afaf**********)]` maybe it should be: `[TestVariable("afaf**********")]`

Comment: this code is generated using Ranorex. I added an data to excel file and data binded to fname.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I have used and that works is to create a global variable and bind it to the module variable and then in the testcase/module that you need that value, use the global variable which now is assigned with the value of the module variable.

You can do it like this

1. Create global variable in the test suite- var_global
2. Create module variable in module 1- fname
3. In module 1, assign the module variable to global variable -

   TestSuite.Current.Parameters["var_global"] = fname
4. Create a module variable in module 2 = var_mod2
5. Use the global variable

   var_mod2 = TestSuite.Current.Parameters["var_global"]